# Problems with jquery animate left in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a 100% width/height content 'slider' that uses buttons as well as anchor links to jump to slides.

I'm not great with javascript or jquery so I'm on a bit of learning curve with this as it is, but I've got the slider to work in both Chrome and Firefox, but having huge issues with Safari. Code below:

```
var $proj = $('div.project') //Cache your DOM selector
    visible = 1, //Set the number of items that will be visible
    indexProject = 0, //Starting index
    endIndexProject = 9; //End index 

$('.workR').click(function(){
     if(indexProject < endIndexProject ){
       indexProject++;
      $proj.animate({'left':'-=9.0909%'});
    }
});

$('.workL').click(function(){
     if(indexProject > 0){
       indexProject--;            
      $proj.animate({'left':'+=9.0909%'});

    }
});

/* sub project nav */


$("#one").click(function(e) {
    indexProject = 0;
    $proj.animate({'left':'0%'});    
});

$("#two").click(function(e) {
    indexProject = 1;
    $proj.animate({'left':'-9.0909%'});    
});

$("#three").click(function(e) {
    indexProject = 2;
    $proj.animate({'left':'-18.181334059343435%'});      
});

$("#four").click(function(e) {
    indexProject = 3;
    $proj.animate({'left':'-27.272243150252528%'}); 
});

$("#five").click(function(e) {
    indexProject = 4;
    $proj.animate({'left':'-36.363152241161615%'}); 
});

$("#six").click(function(e) {
    indexProject = 5;
    $proj.animate({'left':'-45.454143287515365%'});   
}); 

$("#seven").click(function(e) {
    indexProject = 6;
    $proj.animate({'left':'-54.544854594875545%'});
});

$("#eight").click(function(e) {
    indexProject = 7;
    $proj.animate({'left':'-63.63566105915084%'});
});

$("#nine").click(function(e) {
    indexProject = 8;
    $proj.animate({'left':'-72.72647748412166%'});
});

$("#ten").click(function(e) {
    indexProject = 9;
    $proj.animate({'left':'-81.81728394679116%'});
});
```

Basically all the project divs are part of a really long div and are moving along by their width on click of the left & right arrows. The anchor links work fine.

On the first slide, click the right arrow brings in the second slide repeatedly and then the left arrow doesn't go back to the first slide, it goes to a blank screen as it's now at style="left: -72.72099260025185%;" rather than going back to zero.

On the second slide when inspecting the code, rather than all the slides moving along the same percentage, they are all moving by slightly different percentages.

If anyone could explain why this doesn't work in Safari and point me in the right direction, it'd be much appreciated! Kind of at a brick wall in the answers I've found and not really knowing what to do next. Thank you.

**edit**

Ok so I now know that animating percentages is buggy in Safari, so now I know it's the percentages causing the erratic behaviour. Further digging bought me to this piece of code:

```
percent = 0.90909; 
add_width = (percent*$proj.parent().width())+'px';
$proj.animate({'left': '-='+add_width}, 500);
```

which works, but obviously doesn't behave quite how I want it to when resizing the browser. Is there any workaround to make percentages work in Safari or a way of making just the pixel calculated stuff target Safari? Realise I may be clutching at straws here?! Ha.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but since no one has answered and I ran into this similar problem in Safari just now... if your parent container is 100% width and that width is the same size as the viewport ( the browser window width ) ... then you could use this:

```
$proj.animate({'left': '-=100vw' }, 500); //Where 100vw is 100% of the viewport width.
```

You run into issues if your parent container isn't as wide as the viewport, but in most cases with some quick math, you can figure out what the calculation might be.
Anyways, you can find more useful info here : http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units